# How to vectorise a loop ARM Neon

Tags: c++, arm, neon

I have a loop as given below in a c++ class which performs cholesky factorisation where A,B,C,D and E are integer arrays.

```
int i = 10;
for (int j = A [i] + 1 ; j < C [i] ; j++)
{
  E[D [j]] -= B[j] * val ;
}
```

At each iteration, one element of the array is updated and accumulated to a different index of E. How can I effectively vectorize this loop for optimisation using ARM Neon intrinsics?

Comment: I'll stick my neck out and say that this is never going to vectorize with NEON, since you would need gathered loads and scattered stores for the `E[D[j]]` access, which NEON does not support.

Comment: You should reconsider your algorithm. They way it's implemented, its performance will suffer heavily from cache misses.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE that may be the reason why the loop is the bottle neck. can u give any suggestion on updating the loop for minimizing cache misses?